# Is there any integration available for phing with netbeans?

Tags: netbeans, phing, netbeans-plugins

I could not find any phing plugin for netbeans

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give the Ant plugin try. Because the syntax is very similar to ant you'll at least get nice target overview in the Navigator instead of the default xml structure overview. Better than nothing.

Comment: :( not the answer I was hoping for.

Answer (score 1):

http://plugins.netbeans.org/plugin/47165/phingking
There was not a plugin before but now there is PhingKing

Answer (score 1):

NetBeans 8.1 Beta comes with phing support: https://blogs.oracle.com/netbeansphp/entry/phing_support_added

I've already tested it and it works quite well.